# Is it possible to make changes to a page source content variable through Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

Is it possible to make changes to the page source content **through Ajax** loaded by a `jsp` include in the main `jsp` ?

If not is it possible to reload that portion of the page alone (the `jsp` that loads some of the content) and to have a portion of the content in the page source changed ?

**Details**:

I've a variable called `page` this var gets its content from a java controller as a map of `<String key,map<String key,String value>`then it performs multiple actions and adds different `params` to the map, convert it to JSON and sends it to a `jsp`.

Recently I wanted to do something different,I want to add a param to the `'page'` variable called `contentOfThePage` this variable gets its content dynamically when the document is fully loaded, after that I perform an `Ajax` request to the controller to add the new param, but the problem is that the new changes never makes it to the page source unless i reload the page or i navigate to another page and this is causing a lot of trouble as the page source may contain the page content of the previous page!

Any idea on how to avoid this and make changes to the **page source (NOT DOM)** directly ?

keep in mind that the contents are added dynamically but i need a way to change the page source without impacting the performance by requesting a reload after the ajax request succeeded

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for DOM history API to handle current page state using `pushState`:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API   Because you cannot change the page source client side. The page source is what is returned by server

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to add more javascript after the page has finished loading. However with my experiences, the page will use caching after it has fully loaded, and thus will not think about running any javascript unless specificly told to (such as onclick event). This can be changed if you prevent your page from caching. (Note my experiences come from purely html-js (pure javascript ajax), seeing as the things  you are using varies a little, your case may differ from mine.

Comment: @A.Wolff that's the problem i need a way to re-request the HTML from the server without impacting the performance, or at least hold the response till the AJAX performs its part

Comment: can you share your code in the question? Because what ever you are want is widely used by many coders and it is fully possible to do it.
But still there are lot of question arises from your question.

Comment: I don't understand the question after some minutes reading. If you improve it you might get more answers. What does "page source js variable" mean? The question is missing dots at the end of sentences. This is hard to read and leads to ambiguities. Last but not least, the important parts of the code might help to understand.

Answer (score 1):

First You want to update some data that is already there after page load

you already have a json so a rest call i assume 
you call it using ajax

now you added something else that you want to change

Yes it can be done actually

but not with the present set 
i assume you have a single jsp and trying to change that jsp

well fit whatever you want to change in a panel like a graph or anything else 
Add a button to top of the panel and on click the button url must be to the rest call so then data will be updated

*I too have faced a similar problem with graphs, 
i needed the graph to give updated data without refreshing the whole page, 
so i put it inside a panel and wrote a rest controller that gives data for the graph and put a refresh button that calls this rest controller. This let me then update the graph without refreshing the rest of page*